# Running a command in all folders under a parent subdirectory

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a case where I have N number of sub folders under a parent folder X. The folder names are not in any order.

I have a requirement where I have to go into each of these subfolders and perform a specific task or run a command (for example create a text file called new.txt).

How can I do this?

Comment: This topic have no relation with _arrays_. You should change the title...

Answer (score 1):

Put the script bellow in a bat file and place it in the root directory tree. Run it. It will create file new.txt in all folders. You can replace this command or add others. `%%a` is the folder path.

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B /S /AD') do (
    rem command to execute for each folder
    type nul >"%%a\new.txt"
)
```